# Understanding how to obtain Nelson Siegel Svensson parameters

Tags: fixed-income, bond, yield-curve

I am trying to determine the parameters for the Nelson Siegel Svensson model and am solving a Non- Linear Optimization problem to do this. I am using the procedure presented in [this paper](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2mNOF_yPvqAJ:www.vse.cz/polek/download.php%3Fjnl%3Defaj%26pdf%3D9.pdf%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).

The way I am currently thinking of the set-up is as follows:

Bond 1 is associated with vector $m_1$ which contains all the differences between times to maturity and times of each of the payments for Bond 1. For example, if Bond 1 has 24 months to maturity and has semi_annual coupons $m_1 = [18,12,6,0]$. However, the paper suggests that even the face value needs to be included in $c_{ij}$. But the equation $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{l_i}c_{ij}*d(m_{ij}, \theta)$ gives a very low value for the price of the bond as the  $d(m_{ij}, \theta)$ values are turning out to be very small (of the order 10^-34 through to 10^-1, for each bond, as the differences between times to maturity and time of the payment decreases).

*So, am I correct in thinking that each bond is associated with a different discount factor vector as $m_{ij}$ changes for each bond?*

**I guess my main issue is, am I interpreting $m_{ij}$ correctly and hence correctly calculating the discount factors the right way, as I find that they are very small and hence the prices are very small and only got a reasonable answer for the parameters when I take the discount factor to be 1 when $c_{ij} = Face value + Coupon$**

Also, I realize in the paper I have cited they just consider the Nelson Siegel model, however in the code I have written below I account for the extra parameters associated with the Nelson Siegel Svensson model.

This is the code that I am using to determine the prices, where `df` contains all  the observed market data:

```
def calculatingprices(df, beta_0, beta_1, beta_2, beta_3, tau_1, tau_2):
    #I am just creating a dict 'd' which will have the months to maturity for each bond as keys and 
    #a list as its values. The lists will contain the months to maturity - payments associated 
    #with the bond 
    months_to_maturity_matrix = df['months_to_maturity'].values
    number_of_rows = df.shape[0]
    theoretical_price_for_bonds = np.zeros((number_of_rows, 1))
    d = {}
    for months_to_maturity_bond in months_to_maturity_matrix: 
        l = []
        #Adding the difference in dates to the dict d. Differences, will just be multiples of 6 upto 360 (i.e. the 30 year bond)
        for i in range(6, 360, 6):                  
            if i <= months_to_maturity_bond:
                l.append(months_to_maturity_bond - i)
            else:
                l.append(0)    
                d[months_to_maturity_bond] = l                  
        d_ordered = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))

#I then use the formula for the discount factor as follows
    for x, value in np.ndenumerate(months_to_maturity_matrix):
        diff_between_maturity_and_payments_array = np.array(d_ordered[value])
        years_diff_between_maturity_and_payments_array = diff_between_maturity_and_payments_array/12
        theoretical_discount_factor = np.exp(-years_diff_between_maturity_and_payments_array * (beta_0 + ((beta_1 + beta_2)*((1-np.exp(-years_diff_between_maturity_and_payments_array/tau_1))/years_diff_between_maturity_and_payments_array/tau_1))-(beta_2*np.exp(-years_diff_between_maturity_and_payments_array/tau_1)) + (beta_3*(((1-np.exp(-years_diff_between_maturity_and_payments_array/tau_2))/years_diff_between_maturity_and_payments_array/tau_2) -np.exp(-years_diff_between_maturity_and_payments_array/tau_2)))))
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Say at time $t$ , the cash flows of some bond $b$ can be described by the two vectors $\textbf{c}$ and $\textbf{t}$, containing information about the value of the nominal cash flows and cash flow times in years, respectively. Similarly, if we have a range of bonds $B = \{ b_1, ..., b_n\}$ that trade on a market, the matrices $\textbf{C}$ and $\textbf{T}$ contain information about the cash flows and cash flow times for all bonds on the market (in this example, assume that each bond occupy one row).

Assuming no-arbitrage and term-invariant default risk, the vector $\textbf{p}$ of dirty prices for the bonds trading on the market can be recovered using the expression
$$
\textbf{p} = diag(\textbf{D(T)} \textbf{C}^T)
$$
where $\textbf{D(T)}$ is a matrix of **observed** discount factors corresponding the the individual entries in $\textbf{T}$; for instance $\textbf{d}_{i, j} = e^{-r(\textbf{t}_{i,j})\textbf{t}_{i,j}}$, where $r(t)$ is some function for the spot (or zero coupon) term structure.

In the real world, instead of solving for $\textbf{p}$, we can in fact *observe* $\textbf{p}$ through our broker or on our Bloomberg terminals, and so we wish to estimate $\textbf{D(T)}$ instead.

So, you've chosen to model $r(t)$ using the NSS parametric model (sometimes referred to as a *parsimonious model* when comparing with other models of potentially many more predictors). We then choose an objective function, say
$$
\min_\theta{\sum{(p_i - \hat p_i)^2}}.
$$
Here, $p_i$ is the observed dirty price of the $i^{th}$ bond and $\hat p_i$ is the fitted dirty price of the $i^{th}$ bond and $\theta$ is a vector of estimation parameters in our model. We then simply employ some numerical optimization routine on our parameter vector $\theta$ until we find an optimum.

I hope this helps to not only see how to estimate parameters in the NSS model, but also why it is theoretically more consistent to model **spot rates** over **nominal coupon YTMs** (the latter of which I believe you've tried to model, if I interpret your question correctly).

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of some of what you said and am using the spot rates. However, it does answer one of my questions as to whether each bond is associated with a different factor array, which they are.

Comment: @PhysicsEnvy Would you be able to shed some light on my other question:  Should I take the variable m_ij (time to maturity - time of payment for the bond) described in the paper as 0 at the time to maturity, as this results in a discount factor of 1?